# command | grep | awk | ..... how to execute

Tags: command-line, awk, pipe

so i have this command 
`ps ax | grep apache | awk '{ print "cat /proc/"$1"/status | grep State" }'`
which outputs something like

```
cat /proc/9989/status | grep State 
cat /proc/9992/status | grep State 
cat /proc/9993/status | grep State 
cat /proc/9994/status | grep State
```

But i'd love to go one step forward and execute those lines. So i am missing something after awk command to run the output. something like `| exec` or alike .

Is this possible ?

Comment: `pgrep apache | xargs ps -o pid=,state= -p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to piping the commands to a shell as icarus correctly said, `awk` can execute a shell command itself:

```
  ps ax | grep apache | awk '{ system("cat /proc/"$1"/status | grep State") }'
```

But you don't need `cat` because `grep` can read a file as RomanPerekhrest quietly showed:

```
  ps ax | grep apache | awk '{ system("grep State /proc/"$1"/status") }'
```

And you don't need the second `grep` because `awk` can read a file and match a regexp:

```
 ps ax | grep apache | awk '{F="/proc"$1"/status"; 
      while((getline <F)>0) if(/State/) print; close(F)}'
 # if maxfiles is enough you don't need the close(F)
```

nor the first one:

```
 ps ax | awk '/apache/{F="/proc"$1"/status"; 
      while((getline <F)>0) if(/State/) print; close(F)}'
 # ditto
```

But you don't really need to look at `/proc` because `ps` already outputs the state, albeit abbreviated:

```
 ps ax | awk '/apache/{print $3}'
 # or print $1,$3 to include PID like Kusalananda's ps-based answer
 # or better check $5~/apache/ to avoid including processes that 
 # aren't _running_ apache but have apache in their _arguments_
```

Answer (score 4):

**pgrep** + **xargs** approach:

```
pgrep apache | xargs -I {} grep State "/proc/{}/status"
```

The exemplary output would look like:

```
State:  S (sleeping)
State:  S (sleeping)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just after the current state of the currently running `apache` instances, then you're jumping through quite a number of hoops.

You may use

```
$ pgrep apache | xargs -n 1 ps -o pid=,state= -p
12206 S
12821 S
12872 S
12873 S
13084 S
```

This will use `pgrep` to get all the PIDs for all running `apache` processes and give them to `xargs`. `xargs` will run `ps` to query the state for the given PIDs, and will give you back a list of PIDs and their current state.

The `=` at the end of `pid=` and `state=` will prevent a header from being printed for that column.

For a list of what the single-letter states mean, check the `ps` manual on your system.

---

The above command is also portable to Unices without the Linux `/proc` filesystem, though state information may be presented in a different form. This is on OpenBSD with `apache` replaced by `ksh` for testing:

```
$ pgrep ksh | xargs -n 1 ps -opid=,state= -p
22007 INsp
94426 IN+p
46726 INsp
70684 INsp
 5224 INsp
 9116 SNsp
```

Answer (score 3):

The command you want in place of "exec" is "sh". Your awk program is outputting a shell script, so just feed it to the shell!

Other answers suggesting you are doing too much are correct, for example you don't need both grep and awk as awk can filter it's input.